# "flank" on T-shirts

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-play

I saw branded T-shirts that have "flank" on it.
I know flank means that side part of the body above hips.

Is there any other cool meaning?
Is it sarcastic or something?

I wonder if it really meant nothing but "side of the body".

Thanks!

Comment: **Flank** can also mean the extreme right or left of a military formation, a team, or a gaming area, so the brand might be intended to imply that the wearer is in a state or position far from the mainstream in some way.

Comment: Who knows why people put dumb things on tee-shirts?